# Install available plugin from Plugin Manager, error : Installation of *** failed

Tags: notepad++

Install available plugins from Plugin Manager, error : Installation of *** failed. How to solve the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've faced this exact issue.

Could you check whether your notepad ++ is in the firewall blocklist.

Or you can try this method:

Try a manual install of the plugin manager:

```
1.Close notepad++
2.Download the latest plugin manager PluginManager_1.3.5_UNI.zip`from http://sourceforge.net/projects/npppluginmgr/files/v1.3.5/`
3.Unzip the downloaded file
4.Copy plugins\PluginManager.dll to your notepad++\plugins directory
5.Restart notepad++
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  It maybe download plugins links are blocked by country

Comment: These steps don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with that version of Notepad++.
They mentioned in their git repo as well and now in the new version of 2019 its fixed.
Now they provide plugin manager out of the box in Notepad++ when we install the software unlike previous scenario mentioned in the question when we need to use third party plugin managers.

Answer (score -1):

It happens to me, but just for plugins stored at github.
However, I can install plugins at Sourceforge and others.

If you are using an enterprise computer it can be caused by domain policies.

try with 
 - Go to Control Panel, Internet options,Advanced, 
 - On Security section, enable TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2